# cannot extract elements from a scalar

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql, jsonb

I have 2 tables company and contacts. Contacts has addresses JSONB column.
I tried a select statement with a join on contacts.linked_to_company and using jsonb_array_elements(company.addresses) but I get error 'cannot extract elements from a scalar' which I understand is because some entries do have [null] in column address. I have seen answers to use coalesce or a CASE statement. Coalesce I could get to not work and CASE example is in the select statement how do use it in a join?
Here is the sql

```
SELECT company.id,
trading_name, 
nature_of_business, 
t.id contactID, 
address->>'PostCode' Postcode,
position_in_company
FROM contact t FULL JOIN company ON (t.company_linked_to = company.id ),
jsonb_array_elements(t.addresses) address
  WHERE
 t.company_linked_to ='407381';
```

here is example jsonb

```
[{"PostCode":"BN7788","Address":"South Street","AddressFull":"","Types":[{"Type":"Collection"}]}]
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can try one of these (instead of `jsonb_array_elements(t.addresses) address`):

```sql
jsonb_array_elements(
    case jsonb_typeof(addresses) 
        when 'array' then addresses 
        else '[]' end
    ) as address
-- or
jsonb_array_elements(
    case jsonb_typeof(addresses) 
        when 'array' then addresses 
        else '[{"PostCode": null}]' end
    ) as address
```

The first one hides rows with improper json format of the column, the second one gives `null` for them.

However, the problem actually stems from that one or more values in the column is not a json array. You can easily fix it with the command:

```sql
update contact
set addresses = '[null]' 
-- or
-- set addresses = '[{"PostCode": null}]'
where jsonb_typeof(addresses) <> 'array' or addresses = '[]';
```

After this correction you won't need `case` in `jsonb_array_elements()`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, if i would like to retrieve all information from jsonb i.e. Address, AddressFull, would every field in jsonb have to be nulled in ELSE statement were there is no valid 'array'?

Comment: Data correction is a better solution, see the updated answer.

Comment: The answer I was looking for! Helping to resolve the case issue and SRFs caused by Postgresql 10 update.  Move the case inside the jsonb_array_elements instead outside it.  Also a reference to a blog for other passersby: https://tapoueh.org/blog/2017/10/set-returning-functions-and-postgresql-10/