# Postgesql and JsonB: How to query list nested in an object

Tags: arrays, postgresql, jsonb

I've looked at example after example, and I cannot find the syntax for what I need to do. With the below jsonb data, can someone tell me how to query the `lastUpdatedTimestamp`?

```
{
    "name": "Company name",
    "professionalData": [{
            "unit": "unit 1",
            "id": "1228",
            "school": "University of California-Berkeley, Haas School of Business",
            "quarter": "Q1",
            "lastUpdatedTimestamp": "2020-10-27T18:05:00Z"
        },
        {
            "unit": "unit 2",
            "id": "1228",
            "school": "University of California-Berkeley, Haas School of Business",
            "quarter": "Q1",
            "lastUpdatedTimestamp": "2020-10-29T12:10:00Z"
        }
    ]
}
```

I can get the `professionalData` object, but how do I then get an element within the array nested in `professionalData`? This is my exact query:

```
SELECT 
    elements
FROM product_reference_master p,
    jsonb_array_elements(p.prd_ref_dta_mas_json->'professionalData') as elements
```

And I get an error: `ERROR: cannot extract elements from an object`

I'm using Postgresql Aurora in AWS. I'm unsure of the exact version...

Comment: Always specify the version you are using.

Comment: Thanks, of course. I'll edit my question.

Answer (score 1):

[demos:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=68bc7e3283dd342447dedfc6b2d78d2f)

Expand the array with `json_array_elements()` and then you can query the inserted fields:

```
SELECT 
    elements -> 'lastUpdatedTimestamp'
FROM product_reference_master p,
    json_array_elements(p.prd_ref_json::jsonb->'professionalData') as elements
```

From **Postgres 12**, you can use `json_path_query()` alternatively:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM product_reference_master p,
    jsonb_path_query(p.prd_ref_json, '$.**.lastUpdatedTimestamp') as elements
```

Comment: I tried something like that, but I get this error: `ERROR: cannot extract elements from a scalar`. `professionalData` is an object, not an array. Instead, it contains an array.

Comment: Then something else seems to be wrong: For me it works: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=1299affc4bd63d2d9445e3d0f8aa7fc9 Please try to reproduce your setting in the fiddle and share the related link afterwards

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: My fiddle works as well, but the example isn't applying to my database. I still get an error that `professionalData` is a scalar object. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=80ba6c8302c0feadd70b4c6af2666dca

Comment: Maybe not all your data is type JSON? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50296102/cannot-extract-elements-from-a-scalar Meaning: Your are casting text into json. Maybe not every record contains the expected structure?

Comment: The column is definitely jsonb, and it's valid. I checked. I'll update the question with the latest part of your query that I'm using.

Comment: Can we go into a chat? I'd feel more comfortable showing you the exact data there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227611/discussion-between-cndyson-and-s-man).